# Data in Excel add-in

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

How would I go about extracting data from an Excel sheet into a list in an Excel Add-In? Ideally I would need to get each row from a sheet and save it in a list of tuples in the add-in.

It's a C# add-in and the data will be stored within the add-in in a worksheet. The data doesn't need to be stored from session to session. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't say what kind of addin, what programming language you are using,and its not clear if you want to persist the data within the addin from session to session. <br>If its an XLA/XLAM addin you can store the extracted data on a worksheet inside the addin.<br>

Comment: @CharlesWilliams sorry, its  c# add-in and the data will be stored within the add-in in a worksheet like you said. The data dosent need to be stored from session to session.